# Tree labeling and node drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

How can I add the label to the alternative paths (y_1, y_2, a_1,a_2...exc) and how can I transform the second children in squared as in figure 1, using forest?

This is my code:

```
\begin{forest}
    [,circle, draw,grow=east
      [,circle, draw,grow=east,[,grow=east][,circle, draw,grow=east[...,grow=east][$u(a_1;\theta_1)$,grow=east]]][,circle, draw,grow=east[,grow=east][,circle, draw,grow=east[$u(a_1;\theta_2)$,grow=east][$u(a_1;\theta_1)$,grow=east]]]
    ]
\end{forest}
```

And figure2 is what I got.[image]

[image]

Comment: welcome new contributor -- the code in its present form does not compile -- you need to upload the entire code in it s minimal form as a MWE to produce the figure 2-- that may get a better response

Comment: It's helpful to include a complete example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` because the missing stuff can affect the output. My answer will work if you have a bog-standard preamble, but might not if you're using, say, the `linguistics` library.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a vanilla preamble i.e. load `forest` with no libraries etc.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={grow=east,l sep'+=2em,s sep'+=1em},% l sep controls the length of branches, s sep controls how much they're pushed apart
  before typesetting nodes={
    where={>O_=O_=!&{content}{}{n children}{0}}% if there's no content but there are children
    {draw,
      if level=1{regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4}{circle}
    }{anchor=parent},% if there is content or there aren't children, align anchors towards parent
  },
  my label/.style={if={>O_={n}{1}}{edge label={node[below,midway,font=\scriptsize]{$#1$}}}{edge label={node[above,midway,font=\scriptsize]{$#1$}}}}% if it's the first child, put the label below; o'w put it above
    [
      [,my label=y_2[,my label=a_2][,my label=a_1[$\cdots$,my label=\theta_2][$u(a_1;\theta_1)$,my label=\theta_1]]]
      [,my label=y_1[,my label=a_2][,my label=a_1[$u(a_1;\theta_2)$,my label=\theta_2][$u(a_1;\theta_1)$,my label=\theta_1]]]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: labelled tree]